# Train object detection models based on CNN on CPU only

Tags: conv-neural-network

Since we have object detection models based on CNN such as Fast RCNN, Faster RCNN, YOLO (You only look once), ssd (single shot detector).
I have tried running Faster RCNN using CAFFE but backward path is not implemented for CPU mode. Is there any CNN based model which I can use it to train using CPU.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

faster-rcnn layers in CPU: https://github.com/neuleaf/faster-rcnn-cpu
SSD's [original implementation](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) already supports CPU training.